# TinyMCE inside jQuery UI-tabs doesn't size right in ui-tabs if not on initial selected tab (jsFiddle example)

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-ui-tabs

If TinyMCE is in jQuery ui-tabs, it will only properly size if in the 1st tab (or the tab selected to be open when ui-tabs is created).   On every other tab, TinyMCE will only have a couple of lines and will only be as long as the toolbars.

I haven't been able to figure out any way to solve this.

On the jsFiddle demo below, run it and you'll see only the TinyMCE editor on tab 1 is sized properly.   Then ---

CHANGE:

`$('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);`

TO:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

And, run again.  You'll see that since the 2nd tab is now open by default, only the TinyMCE window on that tab is sized properly.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/StacyMc/f8jbU/3/)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to solve this, is to initialize the tabs after the initialization of tinymce, by adding:

```
oninit : function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
},
```

to the initialization options of tinymce.

It's not particularly elegant, because the user briefly sees the page in it's pre-tabbed state, but it does work and I was unable to find a way to make tinymce dynamically resize.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem with tinyMCE and jQuery.

After googling with no avail, i try to put inline css in the textarea and now it works fine :D

try on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNyqT/)
or
here is my snipet:

css:

```
.editor { width: 450px; }
```

html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <textarea class="editor" style="width: 450px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <textarea class="editor" style="width: 450px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <textarea class="editor" style="width: 450px"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
    $('textarea').tinymce({
        script_url: 'http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Reu's idea, what I did is initially position the divs for each tab way off the screen (e.g. left: -3000px), then initialise the tinyMCE instances and add an oninit: parameter to call a function. Then in this function I initialise the tabs and reposition the divs back to the correct position.

It's a bit of a hack but it does work perfectly